# Android Add File in File array

Tags: android, file

I have a list of file name(filelist) and I would like to retrieve and store it into File array (files ).

But I don't know how to do read the file and store into it. Means I like to add file in the filelist into files. How can I achieve this?

```
public static File[] files; 
private List<String> filelist;
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
files = targetDirector.listFiles();  
/* This will get all files in that directory, 
   but I just want the file listed in filelist */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this way is better

```
                   files = targetDirector.listFiles(
                    new FilenameFilter() {
                     @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                         //mspoke is List containing name of file needed to read
                         if (mSpoke.contains(name)){

                            return true; 
                         }else{
                             return false;
                         }
                     }
                   }

                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = targetDirector.listFiles();
```

this line will give you the list  of files  contain by that path directory .

> But i don know how to do read the file and store into it.

You can read it like

```
 for (int i=0 ; i< files.length ; i ++)
  {
     //To Read 

     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file[i] );
     String read;
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

     while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(read);
          }
     Log.d("File Out", builder.toString());
     bufferedReader.close();


    // To Store file 

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(file[i]);
    bufferedWriter.write("File is writing..... ");
    bufferedWriter.close();

 }
```

Comment: i think will work, but i found a shorter version to read the needed files. Thanks.